# Does the attempt to write a document cost a write operation in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I use the following line of code for the first time (when database is empty), my user is correctly added to the database.

```
db.collection("users").document(uid).set(userObject);
```

If I use the same line of code again, the user is not added anymore, obviously because is already there.

My question: Does the attempt to write a document that already exists in database cost me a write operation?

Is it necessary to get a reference first, check if the `uid` already exists in database in order to write the user? Does this also cost a read operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does the attempt to write a document that already exists in database cost me a write operation?"

Yes, the write is still performed and still billed.

"Is it necessary to get a reference first, check if the uid already exists in database in order to write the user?"

If you know the uid you can always write it without checking first.

"Does this also cost a read operation?"

Yes, reading the document first costs a document read.

Comment: Completely understood! Thank you Dan!

Comment: What about if you use update instead of set and the document does not exist?